# Functional analysis, normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Can you please help me with this exercise.. I have to check if in interval $[a,b]$ continuously differentiable functions $x=x(t)$ norm can be defined as:

$$\vert x(b) - x(a) \vert + \max_{a \leq t \leq b} \vert x'(t) \vert$$

Answer (score 1):

For a constant function $x=x(t)=c$ where $c\ne 0$ we have 
$$\vert x(b) - x(a) \vert + \max_{a \leq t \leq b} \vert x'(t) \vert=\vert c-c\vert+0=0$$
while $x\ne 0$. That is, this function does not possess this property of a norm
$$||x||=0\iff x=0$$